# SQL Server Error while executing XQuery value function

Tags: sql-server, xquery

When I run the below XQuery statement I receive the following error:

Msg 2205, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
XQuery [MyTable.StrikeIronResponse.value()]: ")" was expected.

So I'm missing a bracket apparently.

I know the format is okay because I've applied it to other XML documents and it works fine.

However, this is the first time I've applied to an XML where some of the nodes contain metadata. I think that this could be what's tripping me up.

If anyone can help me spot what I'm doing wrong I'd be really grateful. Thanks for listening. Here's the query:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable

WHERE StrikeIronResponse.value('(SIWsOutputOfVerifyEmailRecord xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/ServiceStatus xmlns="http://www.strikeiron.com/"/StatusDescription/Value)[1]','VARCHAR(8000)')

LIKE'%Email Valid%' AND (DateTimeRecorded BETWEEN'2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-07')
```

Comment: This does not look like any valid XQuery at all, but some mixture of XML element definition with missing angle brackets together with some path expression attached. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Jens, Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Its a valid XQuery alright, I've verified that syntax is correct. I'm trying to read the value contained within the node 'StatusDescription' and check if it is LIKE '%Email Valid%'

Comment: I resolved it. I replaced the first argument of the value() with 

'(//*[local-name()="StatusDescription"])[1]'